# First Expression in a Javascript For Loop - what's with the comma?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm working through an HTML5 drag and drop example http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/, but can't figure out exactly what is happening in the loop at the end of this function-

```
function FileSelectHandler(e) {

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
    }

}
```

As far as I know, the first expression should just be i=0.  What is happening with the `, f`?  As long as the files array contains key i, i gets incremented, f is parsed and it then looks for files[i] again, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `for` loop, you can have multiple initializers separated by commas. That's what you have there, combined with a lazy (and misleading) `var`. In this particular case, it's equivalent to:

```
function FileSelectHandler(e) {
    var i, f, files;

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (i = 0; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
    }
}
```

...because `var` is [badly misunderstood](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) in JavaScript. But probably a better example of using multiple initializers would be:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3], index, len;

for (index = 0, len = a.length; index < len; ++index) {
    // Do something with a[index]
}
```

There, with the misleading `var` removed, we can see that there are two distinct initializers at the beginning of the `for` statement.

Comment: +1 to you, both for your previous corrections to me, and your more complete answer

Answer (score 2):

`, f` simply declares another var `f`. The condition runs until the index `i` is not found in the assignment `f = files[i]` (the assignment returns false breaking the loop). That loop is the equivalent of:

```
for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++){
    var f = files[i];
    // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**It's just declaring a local variable named `f`.**

A (slightly) more jslint-friendly version might be:

```
function FileSelectHandler(e) {
    var files, i, f;

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (i = 0; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
    }
}
```

Variables in JavaScript have function-scope, and hence declaring them at the top of the function makes that clearer.

*(Incidentally, naming ordinary functions with a capital letter is confusing - that's normally used for constructors).*

Answer (score 1):

That's just another variable initialization that runs before your for loop starts.

Since all declarations in JavaScript are hoisted, `i` and `f` are declared at the top of the function; both are initially set to `undefined`.  The loop then initializes `i` to zero, and `f` remains `undefined`.

At each pass of the loop, `f` is set to `files[i]`.  If this new value of `f` is "falsy"—null, undefined, false, empty string, NaN—the loop terminates.  Otherwise the loop executes again.

Comment: Oh my.  That's so obvious now.  Guess I'm used to not declaring vars in the loop.  Is that a bad thing?  Either way, guess I'll change the way I do it now.  Thanks, @Adam.

Comment: +1, but: *"The for loop is declaring `i`, and initializing it to 0, and declaring `f`"* Actually, the `for` loop is doing nothing to declare those variables. The declaration is independent of (and precedes) the `for` loop; it happens upon entry into the function, long before the `for` loop happens.

Comment: @Mark I think the fact you had to ask makes it a bad thing.

Comment: @Mark, No problem - hope that helped.

Comment: @Mark: Worth reading up on how `var` *really* works: *[Poor misunderstood `var`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)*. Putting `var` inside `for` statements is *legal* in JavaScript, but very misleading.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Re your edit: There's nothing "conceptual" about it, it's very real and tangible. Also, the *loop* doesn't initialize `f` at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I said conceptually to try to help OP understand.  Thank you for correcting me (again) on terminology regarding the loop not initializing f.

Comment: @AdamRackis: You're very patient. ;-)

Comment: As much fun as this site is, the real value for me comes from how much I've been able to refine my knowledge, largely courtesy of users like you.  Thanks for *your* patience!

Comment: @Mark - this question was just as much T.J.'s effort as mine, so out of fairness would you mind accepting his answer instead?

Comment: @AdamRackis - Sure thing, Adam.  I had accepted your answer because it was the first posted and it immediately cleared things up for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The , f is just a declaration of a var.  Within the first set of semicolons (var i = 0, f;) is where declarations occur.

Answer (score 0):

`var i=0, f` declares the variables `i` and `f` (and initializes the first to `0`).

If you do not declare `f`, it becomes a global variable which could generate conflicts.